Repair OrientDB Database corrupt
On my Sonatype Nexus Docker instance (install on openshift via Helm), I have a problem at startup : orientdb database analytics seems to be corrupted
2024-07-03 13:22:50,313+0000 ERROR [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Exception during storage data restore
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.ODiskWriteAheadLog.cutTill(ODiskWriteAheadLog.java:919)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.makeFullCheckpoint(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3706)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.recoverIfNeeded(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3937)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:288)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:259)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.connect(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:178)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.createInstance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.instance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:289)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)

I tried to open a console in the pod but when I'm connecting to the database, I have the same error, so I can't use Check and Repair OrientDB command.
I saw on internet that OrientDb have a repair tool in jar format, but I can't find in for my version (2.2.37). Do you know how to fix this problem ?
